# Не могу отобразить код JavaScript  в QTextEdit?

Tags: macos, javascript, qt, c++

Столкнулся со странной для меня проблемой - не получается отобразить текст подобный этому `<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"/>` в QTextEdit. Я загружаю подобный текст на ряду с обычным из базы данных:

```
 QSqlQuery query(string_query, db);
 while (query.next()) {
        ui->textEdit->append(query.value(0).toString());
        qDebug() << query.value(0).toString()
}
```

В qDebug() содержимое высвечивается без проблем, а в `textEdit` присоединяется пустота. Другие тексты отображаются в `textEdit` без проблем. Да - это код `JavaScript` (я собираюсь хранить множество подобных кусков кодов в базе, чтобы по тегам быстро получить необходимый мне кусок кода) и складывается ощущение, что он как бы выполняется.

Как это исправить и очень интересно знать бы почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTextEdit поддерживает форматирование через html теги (цвет и т.д.), и ваш текст распознается некорректно. Попробуйте использовать QPlainTextEdit - можно отдельно задавать обычный текст и с html форматированием.